# Entity Framework 6 code first use the generated key after insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a good practice for saving a unique key of an entity between different application domains?

Meaning:

Each system could have a letter with id: 19. This letter with Id 19 will be different between the different instances of the application.

Each instance of the application has an identifier.

Therefore, I want to save a Unique column between All my application instances wherever it runs.

For instance if a prefix of application is: 23,

The unique key for that telegram between all applications that are run will be - 2319.

Sorry if I mispelled something. Don't really know how to define it in proffesional words.

Say for example my Entity model is the following:

```
public interface IBaseEntityObject 
{
        public int Id {get; set;}
}

public abstract class BaseEntityObject : IBaseEntityObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Letter : BaseEntityObject
{   
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Content {get; set;}

    public virtual Folder Folder {get; set;}
    public int FolderId {get; set;}

    public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
    public int LetterUniqueId {get; set;}
}
```

In my generic repository implementation I have the following method:

```
public T Add(T item)
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Add(item);
}
```

I'd like to send a letter to a different instance my system over Tcp/Ip. 
I need to keep track of the letter between different system because we want to work with acks - Meaning, knowing if the letter was received, read, etc..

```
// In this method I take Letter with LetterUniqueId = null
public bool SendLetter(Letter letterToSend)
{   
    try
        {
            using (var ownedUow = UowFactory())
            {
                var unitOfWork = ownedUow.Value;

                var letters = unitOfWork.LettersRepository;

                var savedLetter = letters.Add(letterToSend);    

                // Save changes happen here
                unitOfWork.Commit();

                *** // Is there a way to execute the following code automatically when adding a letter with EF? I'd pre***

                // _instancePrefix is a unique number saved in configuration for every instance
                savedLetter.LetterUniqueId = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{1}", _instancePrefix, savedLetter.Id));

                // Notifies EF about the update
                letters.UpdateSpecificProperty(savedLetter, letter => letter.LetterUniqueId);

                unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("Could not save the letter in the database", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I hate the fact that I commit twice (save changes twice) in this transaction, but it's necessary because I need to use the key that is generated by EF..

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

If I forgot/ missed some important code, let me know and I'll add it.

Thanks for all helpers

Comment: You *could* investigate (1) a computed column in your database table (if supported by your RDBMS) which would concatenate the `_instancePrefix` and the ID into a combined string, or (2) you could also possibly do this with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the database level

Comment: Do you know of a recommended article regarding those subjects? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: [MSDN on Computed Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx), 
[An Introduction to Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i), [MSDN article on CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I would solve this is to save the instanceprefix in the database and extend Letter like this:

```
public static int GetUniqueId(this Letter letter)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{1}", Letter.InstancePrefix, savedLetter.Id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with saving an entity first and then updating it in the same transaction, with some additional values that are a result of the first save.

It would be possible to use a sequence to generate a unique ID for an entity. For databases that do not support sequences natively, a custom implementation would be needed.

Comment: It requires openning connection to the database twice instead of once, which I assume is not the ideal

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative solution is to take control of the transaction and use generated id before it is committed. Something like:

1. start transaction
2. perform the insert
3. get inserted identifier
4. perform whatever operations are needed
5. commit on success or rollback on any failure

In C#, it should look like this:

```
using (var context = new CustomContext()) 
{ 
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            // various context operations
            context.SaveChanges(); 

            int id = insertedEntity.Id;

            // do stuff with the id 

            dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
            dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

In order to use it along with unit of work pattern, unitOfWork should provide extra methods to allow custom transaction control (`BeginTransaction`, `CommitTransaction`) and also `SaveChanges`. Unfortunately, this kinda defeats the purpose of unit of work pattern (just doing stuff and commit when you are done).

This solution allows greater flexibility, but I would also investigate computed columns solution (credit goes to `marc_s`) before this one. I would not recommend trigger usage.

Comment: Do you know of any useful article about computed colums?? I would appreciate it

Comment: Moreover, my unitofwork.Commit() implmentation is dbcontext.SaveChanges() so basically it's the same

Comment: @S.Peter - If you do not explicitly open and commit/rollback a transaction like in the provided example, EF will automatically wrap all changes when calling `SaveChanges`. So, Commit should remain as it is. Generated id becomes available after entity insertion, not after the transaction commit. It is just that, normally, `SaveChanges` performs save and commit in the same time.

Comment: @S.Peter - [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300(v=sql.120).aspx](MSDN) seem to cover the basics and more. Shortly put, you just add a column to the table: `ComputedCol AS Col1 + Col2`. If possible, put it as `PERSISTED`, to allow faster queries.